# Disable "Handsfree" and "Headset" profiles for specific bluetooth device?

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, sony, blueman

I have Sony's WH1000XM2 Bluetooth headphones.
Unfortunately , with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the only connection procedure that works is as follows:

1. Turn on the headphones.
2. The headphones connect, but to all 3 audio profiles ("AudioSink, "Headset" and "Handsfree").
3. Currently, no sound will be played.
4. I then need to disconnect the "Headset" or "Handsfree" profile (works for both) in BlueMan and then reconnect only the "AudioSink" profile.
5. Sometimes I also need to manually switch to A2DP, but most of the time I dont need to.

So my question is as follows:

1. Can I somehow disable the profiles for this specific device?
2. Can I maybe automate the process somehow?

thanks!

Comment: Same headphones, same problem... Did you ever find out how to streamline the procedure?

Comment: probably very late , didnt get a notification, i did find a script for that, wasnt working stably tho

Comment: @user1796904 can you please share the script?

Answer (score 0):

Fo me this helped to disable Handsfree profile

```
sudo vi /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Add Disable=Handsfree under General

```
[General]
Disable=Handsfree
```

Maybe if you want to disable both you can specify like this Disable=Handsfree,Headset

Restart bluetooth

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```